# Помогите вывести ссылки постраничной навигации

Tags: php, пагинация

Как не пытался ничего не выходит. Смотрел и на отечественных сайтах и на капиталистических.

Нужно вот такого вида:

1 2 [3] 4 5 ... 22

На данный момент у меня вот:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++): ?>
   <a href="?page=<?= $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a>
<?php endfor ?>
```

Счтиает количество записей и количество страничек, а как следует не могу додумать. Выводит только вот так:

1 2 [3] 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

---

В общем, я сам додумался:

```
<?php for($pr = 0, $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++): ?>
   <?php if ($pr = ($i == 1 or $i == $pages or abs($i-$page) < 2)): ?>
      <?php if ($i == $page): ?>
         <span> [<?= $i ?>]</span>
      <?php else: ?>
         <a href="?page=<?= $i ?>"> <?= $i ?></a>
      <?php endif ?>
   <?php else: ?>
      <span> ...</span>
   <?php endif ?>
<?php endfor ?>
```

Но только косяк получился, выводит вот так:

1 ... ... ... ... 6 [7] 8 ... 10

Помогите исправить, пожалуйста))

Comment: квадратными скобками выделена текущая страница? как тогда перейти на следующую? и как будет выглядеть пагинация, если есть 1000 страниц и ты находишься на 500-той?

Comment: Да! Текущая страничка :)

Comment: Это да))) Ну надо конечно, чтобы была возможность на следующую) Это я ерунду написал) Выходит надо как-то так: 1 2 [3] 4 5 ... 22 )))))

Comment: это же ты в качестве упражнения делаешь я надеюсь? потому что есть готовые нормальные реализации пагинации

Comment: Ну можно сказать да)